# Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_msgSend" resolved

Tags: iphone, memory-management

When I try to run my application by xcode, I am getting following message. If I run the installed app in simulator by click on the icon, it is working fine. I don't know why it is giving this kind of issues.

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1469) (Wed May  5 04:36:56 UTC 2010)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 2758.
Pending breakpoint 1 - "objc_msgSend" resolved
```

If anybody having knowledge, please share here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue - it's just telling you that there's a breakpoint in your code, ont the objc_msgSend method.

Though why you would have a breakpoint on objc_msgSend is another thing - you can remove it from the console [using commands](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~consult/info/gdb.html) something like

> delete 1

There's a breakpoint menu in XCode that you can use to remove breakpoints as well but I can't remember where it is right now.